SSD detected but cant see the volume in explorer
I am using a ssd of my old computer, I am unable to see its volume in computer running win 11, it is showing as uninitialized in disk management
I do not want its data
I tried initializing the disk from disk management, but nothing happened
I tried through diskpart using below commands and it gives me error Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found. 

I tried using minitool partition wizard to first wipe the drive and it gives me an error there too "Invalid configure file"
Please give me a solution, the disk is showing healthy when I run a surface test using minitool partition wizard.
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online             0 B      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          238 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 2    Online          931 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 3    Online          238 GB   238 GB

DISKPART> select disk 3

Disk 3 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> attributes cleared successfully

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.653

VOLUME      - Manipulate volume attributes.
DISK        - Manipulate disk attributes.

DISKPART> online disk

Virtual Disk Service error:
This disk is already online.


DISKPART> convert mbr

Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found.


DISKPART> convert gpt

There is no disk selected to convert.
Select a disk and try again.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online             0 B      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          238 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 2    Online          931 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 3    Online          238 GB   238 GB

DISKPART>

DISKPART> select disk 3

Disk 3 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> attributes cleared successfully

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.653

VOLUME      - Manipulate volume attributes.
DISK        - Manipulate disk attributes.

DISKPART> convert gpt

Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found.



nothing happening within disk management and disk part also failing suggests a hardware failure

I mentioned above that the disk is showing healthy when I scanned through the minitool partition tool

Healthy working functioning storage devices allow you to create and delete partitions
